# How can I add data params to an HTML string and get a string back?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a `string` like this:

```
var select_string = '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';
```

I need to add some `data` params to `select` in this string and get this string back in order to get the following:

```
select_string = '<select data-param1="param1" data-param2="param2"><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';
```

I tried to use jQuery functions like `.html()` or `.text()` but it did not work. Like this:

```
select_string = $(select_string).data('param1', 'param1').html() //or .text()
```

Any ideas how to make it work would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) may have answers that are useful to your case.

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr

Comment: I'd be curious why you're doing this operation in the first place. Shouldn't you be working with objects instead of strings?

Comment: See the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/) `Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `attr` to add that attributes to the element

```js
var select_string = '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';

var select = $(select_string).attr({
  'data-param1': 'param1',
  'data-param2': 'param2'
});

console.log(select.prop('outerHTML'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Since your attribute name starts with `data-`, if you want to get the value, you can use:

```
select.data('param1'); // param1
select.data('param2'); // param2
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: Titulum is right, jquery is not needed here. 
But here is the working example usign jquery

```js
var selectString = '<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>';
var $select = $(selectString);
$select.attr("prop_key","prop_value");
var selectChanged = $select.prop('outerHTML');

console.log(selectChanged)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this:

```js
const myElement = document.createElement('div');
myElement.innerHTML = "<select><option>1</option><option>2</option></select>";
const selectElement = myElement.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
selectElement.setAttribute("data-param1", "param1");
selectElement.setAttribute("data-param2", "param2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `indexOf` and `substr()` to split it into 2 parts, insert your new text, and put it back together again.

```js
var first_half = select_string.substr(0, select_string.indexOf('>'));

var second_half = select_string.substr(select_string.indexOf('>'));

select_string = first_half + ' data-param1=\"param1\" data-param2=\"param2\" ' + second_half;
```